# Does the collection of all $0$-$1$ random variables form a set?

Tags: logic, random-variables, set-theory

Where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a probability space, a random variable is a function $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$.

Let us make this simpler... a $0$-$1$ random variable is a function $p:\Omega\to \{0,1\}$.

And now harder...

> *Consider the collection of ALL 0-1 random variables (over all probability spaces). Does this form a set or is there some strange set theory going on when we consider such a huge collection?*

Comment: Do you know about the algebraic structure of random variables?

Comment: @whiteianmotion Based on your comments, I think you've totally misunderstood the question. The collection of all random variables over *all* probability spaces is certainly not a vector space.

Comment: +1 for the question.  However I think the question is a bit unusual: You seem to be asking about the set of all sets $\Omega$. If you already know the set theory concept "the set of all sets is too large to be a set" then it is not clear what further thing your question is asking.

Comment: @whiteianmotion Regarding "In which semester are you?" If you look at the OP's profile page, you will see that they have a PhD in Mathematics and a position at a university. Please try to default to being respectful to other users.

Comment: I have cleared several comments from this question. I want to thank the users involved for not devolving into a flame war. Instead, users flagged comments and moved on --- good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rather trivial example but consider the subset of all random variables such that:

1. The sample space is an ordinal
2. The event space is just $\{0\}$

This collection has a random variable for each ordinal, and hence is not a set.

Comment: +1.  However I think your phrase "event space" means the same thing as "sigma algebra," in which case it looks like each of your sigma algebras has only one set. But a sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ minimally needs two sets (the empty set and the entire sample space).

Answer (score 4):

The Shiranai answer explains that we can make any nonempty set $\Omega$ a sample space, and the "set" of all nonempty sets $\Omega$ is too large to be a set.

However, there is a sense in which there are "just as many" Bernoulli random variables as there are general random variables: We can define two random variables $X$ and $Y$ to be in the same **equivalence class** if they have the same cumulative distribution function (CDF), that is, if $P[X\leq x] = P[Y\leq x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Now define:

- $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of all equivalence classes of Bernoulli random variables.
- $\mathcal{V}$ is the set of all equivalence classes of random variables.

Let $|A|$ denote the cardinality of a set $A$.

#### Claim:

$|\mathcal{B}|=|\mathcal{V}| =|\mathbb{R}|$, where $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the set of real numbers.

#### Proof:

Each Bernoulli random variable $X$ has a distribution that is characterized by a probability $p \in [0,1]$ (where $p=P[X=1]$). Thus, $|\mathcal{B}|=|[0,1]|=|\mathbb{R}|$. It is clear that
$$ \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{V}$$
and so
$$|\mathcal{B}|\leq |\mathcal{V}|$$
By definition, $|\mathcal{V}|$ is equal to the cardinality of all CDF functions. A general random variable $X$ has a CDF $F_X:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is continuous from the right. Thus, the CDF $F_X:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is fully determined by specifying its value $F_X(q)$ for each rational number $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Indeed, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we can obtain $F_X(x)$ as
$$ F_X(x) = \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} F_X(q_i)$$
where $\{q_1, q_2, q_3, ...\}$ is a sequence of rational numbers that approaches $x$ from the right.   So $|\mathcal{V}|\leq |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}| = |\mathbb{R}|$.  In particular:
$$ |\mathbb{R}|=|\mathcal{B}|\leq |\mathcal{V}| \leq |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}| = |\mathbb{R}|$$ $\Box$